# What is this error code telling me? i.e. what do I need to fix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What does this error code mean? (see first answer for error code) I got this while attempting to open a csv file and read the first 5 rows of data.

```
C:\Users\torou>python cleandep/py
python: can't open file 'cleandep/py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

C:\Users\torou>python http://cleandep.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "bit_generator.pyx", line 40, in numpy.random.bit_generator    
File "C:\Users\torou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-2\lib\http://secrets.py", line 20, in <module>    
from random import SystemRandom    
File "C:\Users\torou\http://random.py", line 1, in <module>    
from random import random    
ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from 'random' C:\Users\torou\http://random.py)    
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
File "http://cleandep.py", line 8, in <module>    
import numpy as npy    
File "C:\Users\torou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 150, in <module>    
from . import random    
File "C:\Users\torou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\__init__.py", line 181, in <module>    
from . import _pickle    
File "C:\Users\torou\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\random\_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>    
from .mtrand import RandomState    
File "mtrand.pyx", line 9, in init numpy.random.mtrand
File "mt19937.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mt19937    
File "bit_generator.pyx", line 43, in init numpy.random.bit_generator    
File "C:\Users\torou\http://random.py", line 1, in <module>    
from random import random    
ImportError: cannot import name 'random' from 'random' C:\Users\torou\http://random.py)
```

This is the python 3 code i attempted to run:

```
import numpy as npy
import pandas as pd
data= pd.read_csv("cti-april02-log")
data.head()
```

Comment: Did you name a file `http://random.py`?

Comment: No, I am not sure what random.py is.  I thought it might be a part of numpy...

Comment: why do you have `http://` in front of python `cleandep.py` when you run the command `python http://cleandep.py`?

Answer (score 4):

you have a file named `random.py` that override the module with the same name from the standard library (i.e. it try to import random from your file random.py, not the module in the standard library

Comment: I happened to have a file called `random.py` in a directory, it prevented me from even importing numpy successfully when working there. Apparently, never ever have a file called `random.py`  *anywhere*, it's a ticking time bomb!